# Find existing instance of Office Application

Tags: c#, process, ms-publisher

Is there any way to get existing instance of MS Publisher as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.Application`?

I've found this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft Publisher")
```

So I can check if this is already running, but how to convert it to MS Publisher application? So I can call `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Publisher.Application.Open` for e.g.?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by call Application.Open? What do you need to do?

Comment: Search term - [ROT (running objects table)](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+running+object+table).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try this [Microsoft getActiveObject](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238975). Here's an example.

```
    object word;
    try
    {
        word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
//If there is a running Word instance, it gets saved into the word variable
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
//If there is no running instance, it creates a new one
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
        word = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
```

Hope i helped!

Comment: Can I this way use `object` as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application`?

Comment: The link to  **Microsoft getActiveObject** is broken. Here is the right link: [Marshal.GetActiveObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?view=netframework-4.8)