# Get application ID

Tags: c#, windows, com, system, ole

Do you know how to get applications IDs ("Word.Application" in given example)? What if I will need Excel? Or InDesing?

```
object word;
try
{
    word = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
//If there is a running Word instance, it gets saved into the word variable
}
catch (COMException)
{
//If there is no running instance, it creates a new one
    Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
    word = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

[Find existing instance of Office Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361795/find-existing-instance-of-office-application/31361943#31361943)

Comment: What you mean by *application ID* BTW?

Comment: Where are you starting from? That is: what information do you have from which you want to obtain the name? (PS. "Application Id" already has a meaning in COM: and it is another usage of GUID, these names are normally known as a "program ids, or more commonly *progid*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information out with Microsoft's *OLE/COM Object Viewer*.

> You can use the OLE/COM Object Viewer to view a control's interfaces.  [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx)

e.g. going by the Word example, first expand the **All Objects** node:

[image]

...then scroll down to **Microsoft Word Application**.  The version independent ProgID will be shown on the right.  Use that in your application.

[image]

> What if I will need Excel?

As before, scroll until you find *Microsoft Excel Application*.

[image]

Here we can see it is *Excel.Application*.  If you have multiple versions installed and wish to use a specific version, use the ProgId as shown in the **ProgID** field.

---

**Note:** If like me you encounter multiple entries, take the one that shows either a **ProgID** or **VersionIndependentProgID**.

---

Comment: Awsome. Thank you so much.